# Limit number of character after certain character

Tags: mysql, sql, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to limit number of character being shown after specific character in a string. Example:

The number is like : 1424124.991412

What I want is make it shown like : 1424124.99

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
round(1424124.991412, 2);
```

The result will give you 1424124.99

Answer (score 0):

You could set you datatype to DECIMAL(9,2) but i'am not sure if thats what you mean.

Also refer this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html